# LSTM Sequence Learning -- Prediction Result Issues

Tags: keras, sequence, lstm, prediction

I am attempting to implement sequence learning in Python 3.5.2 | Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit) on my windows 10 machine.  I have scoured the internet in order to get as far as I have, but documentation lacks the details I need.  I will share my code and then ask my questions.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow
import keras as krs
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from sklearn.preprocessing import QuantileTransformer, MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

DF = pd.read_csv("./integer_seqn/train.csv", delimiter = ",")
N = DF.shape[0]

data = []
# turn pandas df into list
for rows in DF['Sequence']:
    
    fix = rows.split(",")
    fix = [int(elem) for elem in fix]
    data.append(fix)

# for now I am working with one sequence at a time
D = data[0]
D = np.reshape(D, (len(D),1))
D = D.astype('float64')

# scaling needed since LSTMs are sensitive to large data values
# for this first sequence I use quantile scaling since the data is skewed
scaler = MinMaxScaler((0,1))
X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(D)

# split each sequence into a training and a test set
train_size = int(len(X_train_scaled)*(0.90))
test_size = len(X_train_scaled) - train_size
train, test = X_train_scaled[0:train_size], X_train_scaled[train_size:len(X_train_scaled)]

# creates a data set so that the first column
# is every n-th element in a sequence
# and the second column is every (n+1)-th element in a sequence
dataX, dataY = [], []
time_step = 2
for i in range(0,(len(train)-time_step)):
    
    dataX.append(train[i:(i+time_step),0])
    dataY.append(train[i+time_step, 0])

dataX = np.array(dataX)
dataY = np.array(dataY)

testX, testY = [], []
for i in range(0,(len(test)-time_step)):
     
     testX.append(test[i:(i+time_step),0])
     testY.append(test[i+time_step,0])

testX = np.array(testX)
testY = np.array(testY)

# need to reshape the data so that model.fit will accept it
dataX = np.reshape(dataX, (dataX.shape[0],dataX.shape[1],1))
testX = np.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0],testX.shape[1],1))

# build RNN-LSTM for a sequence
# the number of LSTM nodes is adjustable
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units = 20, input_shape = (1,1)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer = "adam")

model.fit(dataX, dataY, epochs = 100, batch_size = 1, verbose = 0)

# predict using the model (validation with the train set and test with the test set)
trainPredict = model.predict(dataX)
testPredict = model.predict(testX)
# "unscale" the data
trainPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(trainPredict)
dataY = scaler.inverse_transform(np.reshape(dataY,(len(dataY),1)))
testPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(testPredict)
testY = scaler.inverse_transform(np.reshape(testY, (len(testY),1)))
```

I am testing this code on an integer sequence

```
data[0] = [1, 3, 13, 87, 1053, 28576, 2141733, 508147108, 402135275365, 1073376057490373, 9700385489355970183, 298434346895322960005291, 31479360095907908092817694945, 11474377948948020660089085281068730]
```

I am getting some pretty poor predictions.  When I do model.predict(dataX), the order of magnitude is significantly larger than the true predictions.  Additionally, the predictions provided are all the same.  Most recently, I get a 7x1 numpy array filled with the value **1.2242328e+32**.  I get a similar occurrence with model.predict(testX), where I get a 3x1 numpy array filled with the value **1.2242328e+32**, but at least this prediction is closer (though not as close as I would like) to the final element in testY.

My *specific* question is: why is my prediction array filled with the same value?

Comment: Have you printed the network input in order to see if it correct? Very often the input is the problem.

Comment: Hello.  Yes.  I've printed every input and all output.  Input values/shapes match what is expected, and output shape is what is expected.  I read somewhere that it might be that the model outputs the average prediction, but I'm not sure I understand how model.predict(dataX) has a magnitude so large when the input is less than 1e+12.